# Set data from one specific field into a variable with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have to get data from one specific field in my database and set it into a variable (most likely this has to go into the controller), so that i can echo this on multiple pages in my webapplication.

don't know if it's necassery to say, but i make use of the cakePHP framework.

thanks in advance!

Comment: You should consider reading the CakePHP Cookbook.

Comment: Voted down because this is clearly written in the CakePHP manual.  Setting a variable is basically Cake101.

Answer (score 1):

This is in the book, http://book.cakephp.org/view/821/set

```
$this->set('myvar', $data);
```

Will set a `$myvar` in your view.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use this data on multiple Pages in your Web Application, maybe you are better suited with an [element](http://book.cakephp.org/view/97/Elements)